# How to Dismiss 2 Modal View Controllers in Succession?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiviewcontroller

I have 2 view controllers presented modally.

```
A presents B which presents C.
```

When I dismiss C I would like to dismiss B as well. But I am not sure how to do this:

Dismiss C:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]
//[delegate dismissB] //this doesn't work either when i create a delegate pattern
```

Now I am left with B. How can I dismiss B from C?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using the next code in B (right after dismissing C, as you already do):

```
[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

**IMPORTANT**:
Don't do anything in the method after this line.
This view controller (B) probably will be released and deallocated...

**UPDATE**:
Starting from iOS7 the method above is deprecated.
Use the next method instead:

```
[self.parentViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{ /* do something when the animation is completed */ }];
```

Comment: I tried this but it just simply dismisses C. B is still visible.

Comment: Try dismissing C without animation and then dismiss B with animation... BTW, where is this dismissing code located (which class and how is this method called)?

Comment: Dismissing code is located in C in a method called dismissAll. It is triggered by pressing a UIBarButtonItem.

Comment: I was sure that it is located in B when I wrote my answer... The common solution for dismissing modal view controllers is to call a method in delegate (view controller that opened the modal one) and in that method the modal view controller should be dismissed. In your case A should be a delegate of B and B should be a delegate of C; in C you should call a delegate method in B that should dismiss C and call a delegate method in A, that should dismiss B... I hope it is clear enough now.

Comment: This method is deprecated in iOS 7/8 — what should take its place?

Comment: More generic way to dismiss more that one modal view controllers is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44583711/1151916)

Answer (score 116):

Just found out you need to use presentingViewController in iOS 5.

```
[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

A -> B -> C

Running the above code in modal C will take you back to A

Comment: No problem :-) Every example I came across was for pre iOS5 and never worked

Comment: It would be correct to dismiss view controller from presentingViewController using delegate. (According to Apple guides)

Comment: `...dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` is deprecated now. Try `[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: this works on ios7, but in ios8 if B is presented with modalPresentationStyle OverCurrentContextyou have to call the [A dismissController] twice

Comment: Wasn't working for me because I had it in the completion block of controller C's dismiss method... realized of course it wouldn't work, self is nil! lol

Answer (score 15):

This worked for me, very simple

```
// Call inside View controller C    
self.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
self.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Explanation:

If you call dismiss on C, it can only remove C. If you call dismiss on B, it will do the right thing: Remove the topmost modal view controller. The first call therefore removes C (with no animation). The second call removes B.

The easiest way to access view controller B from C is to use the presentingViewController variable.

Answer (score 14):

In B. Put:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Only run one animation.

Comment: For Swift 5, I use this and it works:

self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: false)
self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true)

Answer (score 9):

**In swift 4**

`self.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);`

Answer (score 8):

Check this for swift:

```
self.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
// Swift
presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

// Objective-C
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];
```

Comment: Messaging arguments in Objective-C is not separated by coma, so It will be without coma after "true" for

// Objective-C
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated: true completion: nil]

Comment: B is not dismissed when I add your code and please update your objective c syntax also. remove the comma after true.

Answer (score 2):

I read all the topics and I didn't find a proper answer. If you dismiss B, than C will immediately disappear and create a weird effect. The proper way is to present C as a child view controller with custom animation from the bottom, like:

```
   [b addChildViewController:c];
    c.view.frame = CGRectOffset(b.view.bounds, 0, b.view.bounds.size.height);
    [b.view addSubview:c.view];
    [c didMoveToParentViewController:b];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        c.view.frame = CGRectOffset(c.view.frame, 0, -b.view.bounds.size.height);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
```

And then you simply dismiss B and it all looks much nicer!

Answer (score 1):

You only need one dismiss command.  Just dismiss B, and then C will go away with it.

Comment: this approach seems to be working very nicely.  Anyone out there see any downsides to this approach?

Answer (score 0):

The navigation controller has a "viewControllers" property that is an array - you can set that to a new array minus the two view controllers you want to remove.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Albertos solution, I created a delegate method in B with a block to show a result of deleting an account:

```
#pragma - mark - AddAccountViewControllerDelegate Methods

- (void) dismissToSettings {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void){[DKMessage showMessage:LS(@"Account was successfully created")];}];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, and a better solution was creating a "DismissViewProtocol" as follow:

File: DismissViewProtocol.h

```
@protocol DismissViewProtocol <NSObject>
-(void)dismissView:(id)sender;
@end
```

In my B-modal view, let's response for the delegate method:

in my b.h file:

```
#import "DismissViewProtocol.h"
@interface B-Modal : UIViewController <DismissViewProtocol>
...
@end
```

in my b.m file:

```
-(void) dismissView:(id)sender
{
 [((UIViewController *) sender) dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

In the same B-view controller, when I call the 
Next, in my B modal view, when I call the other modal view C, supposing that for segue:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    ((C-ViewController *)segue.destinationViewController).viewDelegate=self;
}
```

Finally, in my c.h file, lets prepare for the delegate:

```
@property(nonatomic, weak) id <DismissViewProtocol> viewDelegate;
```

And in my c.m file, I just tell my viewDelegate  to dismiss my modal view controller and itself:

```
-(void)closeBothViewControls
{
       [self.viewDelegate dismissView:self];
}
```

And that's it.

Hope it works for all of you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way how to dismiss more that one modal view controller using repeat cycle:

**Swift 3**

```
// In this example code will go throw all presenting view controllers and 
// when finds it then dismisses all modals.
var splitViewController: UIViewController? = self

repeat {
    splitViewController = splitViewController?.presentingViewController
} while (!(splitViewController is UISplitViewController) && (splitViewController != nil))

splitViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer may feel redundant, but the statement below should make sense 
 and you get an idea of how this works.

**Just dismiss the oldest view controller and all other later view controllers go away with this.**

In case of 2 view controllers:

Objective C:

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil]
```

Swift:

```
presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

You can put these `ViewControllers` inside an individual `NavigationController`. And than dismiss the `NavigationController` will cause all these `ViewControllers` to dismiss at once.

https://gist.github.com/ufo22940268/2949fdf59c9860292f263ebb1e8036d7