# Dismiss two modal view controllers

Tags: objective-c, modalviewcontroller

I have a navigation controller which present one modal viewController. From inside this modal viewController I present another modal viewController. All I want is to get back from the last modal viewController to the navigationController (the root viewController).Something similar with popToRootViewController, but adapted for modalViewControllers;

NavigationController -> present Modal ViewController A -> present Modal ViewController B

From modal ViewCOntroller B I want to return to navigationCOntroller.

Is this possible?

Appreciate,
Alex.

Comment: More generic way to dismiss more that one modal view controllers is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44583711/1151916)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem solved :)

I tried

```
[self.parentViewController.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

and works.

Thanks.

Comment: Use `presentingViewController` in iOS 5

Answer (score 31):

In iOS 5 you need to do

`[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]`

Edit: As of iOS 6 `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` is deprecated.

You need to call

`[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{ // Do something on completion}]`