# Dismiss two modal (table)view controllers

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, storyboard, modalviewcontroller

I know there's like 3-5 similar questions here, but non of the answers solves my problem.

I have a ViewController that opens a modal (table)view controller, which opens another one. Both modal view controllers are in fact table view controllers. I'm trying to dismiss both of them from the second one. I tried every accepted answer on similar question, none of them worked for me.

I tried

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:true]

[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:true]
[self.parentViewController.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:true]

[self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:true]
[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:true]
```

When I try options 2, 3 and 5, nothing happens at all. When I use options 1, and 4, I see dismiss modal view animation and the underlying view itself for a moment, and then everything goes back to the second modal view (this time without animation).

I'm starting to think that this have something with the fact that I use tableViewControllers for modal views.

Btw, I'm dismissing modal views in didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Did you try calling 4 then 1?

Comment: I just tried your suggestion and I've got the program behavior just as I get when I use any of these options separately, on their own (I have a brief return to the underlying modal view, and then instant comeback to the last one)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955638/dismiss-two-modal-view-controllers

Comment: @pie. As you can see from my original post, I tried both those answers (from the post you are referencing to) and non of them solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

When you dismiss your `SecondView` set a `BOOL` flag variable in app delegate file and check that variable in your `FirstView`'s `viewWillAppear` method whether SecondView was open and close or not. If so, then  `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:true]`

Comment: -1 Bad architecture option. You are creating a dependency between a `UIViewController` and the `AppDelegate`. When you develop you should think on the long term, and having that kind of approach goes against loose coupling.

Comment: I was inspired by your solution, bug I don't use delegate files. I don't even know what they are, actually.

Answer (score 1):

typical model view controller behavior would suggest that you dismiss the modal view controller from the calling view controller rather than from self.  not a hard and fast rule, but good practice.

to accomplish this, create a protocol:

```
    @protocol MyModalViewControllerDelegate
    - (void)modalViewControllerDidFinish;
    @end
```

and make both the parentViewController and FirstModalViewController be implemntors of this protocol.

```
    @interface FirstModalViewController <MyModalViewControllerDelegate>
```

then in both FirstModalViewController.h and SecondModalViewController.h, add:

```
    @property id<MyModalViewControllerDelegate> modalViewControllerDelegate
```

in both parentViewController and FirstModalViewController, right before calling presentModalViewController:... , set the following:

```
    modalViewControllerAboutToAppear.modalViewControllerDelegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:modalViewControllerAboutToAppear animated:YES];
```

next, in the SecondModalViewController, in the code where you determine that the item needs to be dismissed, call

```
    [self.modalViewControllerDelegate modalViewControllerDidFinish];
```

now, in FirstModalViewController, implement the following:

```
    - (void)modalViewControllerDidFinish:(MyModalViewController*)controller {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]
        [self.modalViewControllerDelegate modalViewControllerDidFinish];
    }
```

and finally, in the parent view controller, you should be able to perform:

```
    - (void)modalViewControllerDidFinish:(MyModalViewController*)controller {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't use delegate files, I did the following:

To `FirstView` add field

```
BOOL mClose;
```

To `FirstView` add method

```
- (void)close
{
    mClose = YES;
}
```

To `FirstView` method `viewDidAppear` add

```
if (mClose)
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

To `FirstView` method which opens `SecondView` add

```
[secondView closeWhenDone:self];
```

To `SecondView` add field

```
FirstView *mParent;
```

To `SecondView` add method

```
- (void)closeWhenDone:(FirstView*)parent
{
    mParent = parent;
}
```

To `SecondView` method which closes it add

```
[mParent close];
```