# Dismiss two modal view controllers with one animation

Tags: animation, view, controller, nested, modal-dialog

I have a the following view controller stack:
A -> B (presented modally) -> C (presented modally).
My objective is to dismiss `C` and `B` AND the animation I want is that `C` **slides down to reveal** `A`.
With both answers listed here below, the animation you'll see is that `C` disappears and the `B` slides down -- which is not the desired animation.

[Dismiss two modal view controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955638/dismiss-two-modal-view-controllers)

[How to Dismiss 2 Modal View Controllers in Succession?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224328/how-to-dismiss-2-modal-view-controllers-in-succession/39518515#39518515)

Answer (score 0):

Have you try:

```
ViewController1.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
ViewController2.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

by default, the animation is "slide down", otherwise you can customize to however you want.

Comment: you would get two animations with your code.  the desired animation is one -- specifically `C` slides down to reveal `A`