# How can I dismiss two modal view controller in succession *with animation*?

Tags: ios, animation, uiviewcontroller

Yes, I know there's exactly same question, but I want to do this with double dismiss animation. 
[How to Dismiss 2 Modal View Controllers in Succession?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224328/how-to-dismiss-2-modal-view-controllers-in-succession)

my code is same as question above,

view controller A (in navigation controller) - modal view controller B - modal view controller C

here's pseudo code

```
notification to B (as delegate)      // I changed order of this two lines, 
dismiss C *without* animation    // but it was same. 

(notification from C, in B)
dismiss B *with* animation
```

If I use animation when I dismiss C, it doesn't work, B will not be dismiss, because dismiss animation of C is playing.

Problem is: I can't start another dismiss animation if there's animation playing.

Can I play dismiss animation in succession?

This is not only problem of dismiss animation, it can be also applied to other iOS animations.

P.S: I think I can use timer to wait until first animation ends, but it is dirty and not stable way, isn't it?

Small Talk: In my program,

- A: article list view
- B: write article view
- C: login view (if user is not logged in)

today, I have to add join view, I have to dismiss 3 views in time lol how can I help this?

Comment: More generic way to dismiss more that one modal view controllers is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44583711/1151916)

Answer (score 24):

iOS 5.0 and higher:

`[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

This works if you have:

```
A - starting view controller
M1 - modally presented by A
M2 - modally presented by M1
```

Put that line of code in M2's view controller class (and a button or whatever to activate it), and it will "reach up" through the hierarchy and tell A to `dismissViewControllerAnimated:...`

However,Rahul Vyas's answer is probably a better approach for cases where you have an unknown number of modal view controllers stretching between "A" and the last Modal view.

Comment: Note that this doesn't dismiss with two animations. There's only one animation. After reading more carefully, I see that the OP specifically asked for two animations. My bad.

Comment: Here is the problem recurring in iOS 8.4 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31396193/impossible-animation-with-dismissviewcontrolleranimated-ios8-4

Answer (score 7):

You can generate a NSNotification and then from the root where your first modal appears dismiss the first modal view controller and all the others will automatically disappear. I have done this in one of my app.

Comment: How do I get the first modal view controller in my root controller? Considering it could be one of many different classes

Comment: You should definitely never use a NSNotification for this kind of communication! But otherwise.. this answer is 5 years old, maybe it was different in 2011.
@Zil: you can while-loop through the presentingViewController property of your controller to get the root controller.

Comment: I ended up always stacking modals on a modal navigation controller and dismissing the navigation controller instead of the modals one by one

Answer (score 0):

You can use [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)] when you want the view to dismiss the modal view. If you call this in both controllers it should work. I have not tried it myself but it seems logical.

I must add that if you need to present multiple modal views in a row maybe you should consider using different paradigms for some of them. For example, the login view could be an alertview instead of a modal view controller.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into similar types of issues trying to get animations to work in succession.  I've been meaning to try the following:

what if you put the call for the second animation (i.e. to dimiss B) inside a call to performSelectorOnMainThread?  That would make me think the second animation would be forced to wait for the first to complete.

I haven't tested it yet though.  Good luck - I'm very curious about what solution you come up with.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove 2 view by using

```
[AviewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Here AviewController is object of A.
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

`[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)]` doesn't work. The second animation doesn't fire.  In iOS 5 you can use `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];` but that's not backwards compatible to 4.0.  I've only had success calling a delegate method that closes the modal view controller before presenting the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked form me, I had A->B, and then a container view "C "over B. Then I wanted C to dismiss back over to A,

The best way that worked for me was calling this my action in view C

```
self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {})
self.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {})
```

This dismissed the Modal C, then dismisses B in a synchronous order. It worked better with the feel of my application