# Remove a View Controller from another UIViewController Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm wondering how would I be able to remove a view controller that the app is not currently on?

Let's say I segue from OldViewController to NewViewController. Once NewVC loads, how can I have it delete the OldVC, while the app is still on the NewVC?

Comment: And what controller do you want to be shown instead of OldViewController?

Comment: A -> B (presented modally over A) -> C (presented modally over B) and you want to return from C to A, right?

Comment: I just edited the post to give an idea of the viewcontroller hierarchy

Comment: Can you post your storyboard? How do you setup each segues?

Comment: I think I'll just rephrase the question so its more straight forward

Answer (score 1):

I've tried [unwind segues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15839298/1689376) and [dismiss nested presentingViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7964871/1689376) solutions, but both still have the issue with intermediate controller being visible during animation.

Then I found this [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37602185/1689376) which I modified with different snapshot generation, since it was not working properly for me.

Probably not the best solution, but still may be helpful.

**Helper extensions:**

```
extension UIViewController {
    func dismissModalStack(animated: Bool, completion: (()->Void)?) {
        guard let snapshot = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.snapshotView() else { return }
        self.presentedViewController?.view.insertSubview(snapshot, at: Int.max)
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: completion)
    }
}

extension UIView {
    public func snapshotImage() -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, isOpaque, 0)
        drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)
        let snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return snapshotImage
    }

    public func snapshotView() -> UIView? {
        guard let snapshotImage = snapshotImage() else { return nil }
        return UIImageView(image: snapshotImage)
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

In the last presented view controller:

```
@IBAction func dismissPressed() {
    self.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismissModalStack(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**Result:**

[image]